# Investigating mssql_connect problems in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, centos

Today, I restarted my CentOS server and after that my PHP application started to fail in accessing our MsSQL server.

```
[Sun Mar 13 23:44:31 2011] [error] [client 88.154.*.*]
PHP Warning:  mssql_connect()
[<a href='function.mssql-connect'>function.mssql-connect</a>]: Unable to connect to server:  85.*.*.109
```

- MsSQL server uses port 1433.
- I'm able to get a connection when I try *telnet ip 1433* to MsSQL server.
- Username and password combination is correct, I'm able to login from another machine.
- Nothing has been changed in security settings of MsSQL server.

How can I see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

did you double check and make sure that ALL of sql server's services have started?

Comment: I can't check that right now but at least I can say I'm able to connect the server via Management Studio and run queries.

Comment: well, i'm guess that the sql browser service might not have started. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx